# Is a person notified when their location is being tracked?

Tags: iphone

If I log in using someone else's Apple ID and their email address to track their iPhone, will they be notified by email?

Comment: What you are describing is almost certainly illegal.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Track someone without their consent by breaking in into their account?

Answer (score 1):

No, a user is not outright alerted that Find My iPhone is being used to track their device's current location. There are certain things that can trigger a warning, though:

- If you lock the phone/send it a message, they would know
- You could check location services to see if the service had used GPS recently, although that wouldn't tell you that it was specifically from Find My Iphone triggered by you
- If the user has new login notifications turned on, they may be alerted that there was a login from a new browser